# How to store user input as an object key in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, key-value

Being new to Firestore I learned, that I should model it like this: [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUQrj.png)

```js
members {
          id: xyz
                  {
                    name: Jones;
                    hashtag: {
                              global: true,
                              digital: true
                             }
          ...
         }
```

Therefore, I would like to store the user input of a "hashtag" form field as a key of the hashtag property and automatically assign the value "true" to the key using Angular 6 (Typescript). My current approach is this:

```js
submit(newName: string, newHashtag: string) {
    if ( newName !== '' && newHashtag !== '') {
      this.member.name = newName;
      this.member.hashtag = { newHashtag: true};
      console.log(this.member);
      // this.membersService.addMember(this.member);
    }
  }
```

As a result, the program always prints out "newHashtag" but not the desired input value. How can I fix this?

```js
export interface Member {
    id?: string;
    name?: string;
    hashtag?: object;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="new Name" #memberName name="name">
  <input type="text" placeholder="new hashtag" #hashtagName name="name">
  <button (click)="submit(memberName.value, hashtagName.value);
   memberName.value=''">Submit</button>
</form>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as JavaScript:

```
const property = 'foo'
const object = {}
object[property] = 'desired value'
```